# How to access function inside a javascript fetch from html page

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a website showing a graph based on some user uploaded json files.
I am using a fetch to get the JSON data from a servlet and i make the graph inside the fetch, this works fine. Only i'd like to make a addData() function to add extra data to the same plot. The problem is i can't access the data outside of the fetch request and i can't acces the addData() function from my html page if it's in the fetch in my javascript file. 
Is there a good way to approach this problem?

my JavaScript code:

```
fetch('/json_storage')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
        let hrdata = myJson[0].heartRate;
        let timestamp = hrdata.map(t => { return t.timestamp });

        let bpm = hrdata.map( b => {return b.bpm});


        let ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        let canvas = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: timestamp,
                datasets: [{
                    label: new Date(timestamp[0]),
                    data: bpm,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,55,0.25)',
                    pointRadius: 0
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'The course of your heart rate during the day'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'hour'
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

        function addData() {
            for (let i =1; i < myJson.length; i++){
                let hrdata = myJson[i].heartRate;
                let bpm = hrdata.map( b => {return b.bpm});
                let timestamp = hrdata.map(t => { return t.timestamp });

                canvas.data.data = bpm;
                canvas.data.labels = timestamp;

                canvas.update();

            }
        }

    });
```

and my HTML code:

```
<button id="addData">Add dataset</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `addData` and `myJson` are scoped inside your promise callback, which is not available outside - either you need to expose those to the global context or write a reusable function which exposes (returns) the `addData`.

I modified your fetch function to a reusable class, where you have access to all the data from its context.

```js
class LineChart {
  constructor(ctx, dataUrl, initialData = []) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.data = initialData;
    this.dataUrl = dataUrl;
    this.canvas = null;
    
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => fetch(this.dataUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
      this.data = myJson;
      this.draw();
      return this.data;
    });

  draw = () => {
    if (!this.ctx) {
      return false;
    }

    let hrdata = this.data[0].heartRate;
    let timestamp = hrdata.map(t => {
      return t.timestamp
    });

    let bpm = hrdata.map(b => {
      return b.bpm
    });

    this.canvas = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: timestamp,
        datasets: [{
          label: new Date(timestamp[0]),
          data: bpm,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,55,0.25)',
          pointRadius: 0
        }]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'The course of your heart rate during the day'
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'hour'
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
  addData = () => {
    alert(`in addData function ${JSON.stringify(this.data)}`);

    for (let i = 1; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      let hrdata = this.data[i].heartRate;
      let bpm = hrdata.map(b => {
        return b.bpm
      });
      let timestamp = hrdata.map(t => {
        return t.timestamp
      });

      this.canvas.data.data = bpm;
      this.canvas.data.labels = timestamp;

      this.canvas.update();
    }
  }
}


//usage
const chart = new LineChart(
  document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
  '/json_storage'
);

document.getElementById('addData').onclick = chart.addData;
```

```html
<button id="addData">Add dataset</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: hi, i tried this solution but keep getting the following error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ctx is not defined
    at LineChart.draw`

Comment: unfortunately it still wont let me access the canvas to push the new dataset

Comment: @BenB sorry! didn't notice the canvas context. now updated the code. Try now

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want would require you to either store the data that's been built so far in a data structure that is persistent in your page. If you are using a UI framework like `React` or `Angular` then you can store it as part of your state, then when someone clicks the "Add Data" button, call a function to modify that state data accordingly and re-render the results.

Another way would be to re-fetch the data and combine it with the added data, but then you would lose any previously added data.

If you're not using a UI framework, have you tried simply keeping the fetched data in a variable defined at the top of your javascript file?  After the fetch, set it in that variable and have a function that does the chart generation separately. Each time the "Add Data" button is clicked, it should first add the data to the previously saved data, and re-render the chart based on the new dataset.

You'll need to separate the storage of the data and the `canvas` from the processing of the data so that when new data is added, the `canvas` can be updated, but that's outside of the scope of the question you're asking, but perhaps something like this would be workable:

```
const allJson = [];
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
const canvas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: timestamp,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: new Date(timestamp[0]),
        data: bpm,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,55,0.25)",
        pointRadius: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "The course of your heart rate during the day"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});

fetch("/json_storage")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(myJson => {
    addData(myJson[0]);
  });

function addData(newJson) {
  allJson.push(newJson);
  let bpm = [];
  let timestamp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < allJson.length; i++) {
    let hrdata = myJson[i].heartRate;
    bpm = bpm.concat(hrdata.map(b => b.bpm));
    timestamp = timestamp.concat(hrdata.map(t => t.timestamp));
  }

  canvas.data.data = bpm;
  canvas.data.labels = timestamp;

  canvas.update();
}
```

Note that I'm just guessing at the right way to prepare the data for the chart since I don't know the exact form of the data coming from the `fetch` and how it's all structured. But the general idea is:

- Setup variables for the data array and the canvas
- Do the initial fetch and set it using `addData`
- Each time you add more data it should extend and display it